# Как обновить ViewController?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, apple

Как мне полностью уничтожить ViewController, чтобы при повторном открытии он снова создался? То есть мне его надо полностью перезапустить.

Comment: Если проект использует ARC, то это он должен делать автоматически при следующем вызове конструктора или же можно ViewController-у присвоить nil, а при повторном открытии вызвать конструктор заново.

Comment: тут важно используете ли вы для него какой-либо контейнер: UINavigationController, UITabBarController, UISplitViewController или кастомный какой-то

Comment: @Nuclominus как мне присвоить nil этому контроллеру из другого класса?
@iFreeman и UINavigationController и UITabBarController использую.

Answer (score 1):

в случае в UINavigationController просто убираем его из стека viewControllers - это единственное, что "держит" его в памяти. То есть например мы хотим удалить какой-то

```
UIViewController *vcToDelete;

self.navigationConroller.viewControllers = [self.navigationConroller.viewControllers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@", vcToDelete]];
```

Answer (score 0):

к примеру:

```
 -(void)hideMyViewController
    {
        if(_myViewController) {  
            [_myViewController release]; // если не используется ARC нужны обе строчки
        _myViewController = nil;    // Если используется ARC, то достаточно одной
        }     
    }
```

Если не нужны UINavigationController и UITabBarController таким же образом присваивайте им nil в методе в котором вы хотите их убрать (при этом не забывайте их удалять в родительском порядке, от "меньшего" к самому  "главному", в Вашем случае скорее так- myViewController, UITabBarController, UINavigationController).
Но как ранее говорил [[@Nuclominus](/users/18262/nuclominus)](/users/18262/nuclominus) при включенном ARC вовсе не обьязательно присваивать nil, т.к. удаление происходит автоматически